# How can global actions be shown on a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that displays attributes of a Person Account instead of directing to the Person Account detail page. The component is not on a lightning page. How can global actions be displayed on the same screen as the lightning component that displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently actions can only be added to a Lightning page, not a Lightning component. If you can add your component to a Lightning page you would then be able to add actions to the page.

Comment: As the product owner, I do want to support actions at the component level -- but I don't have a timeline for it at this time. We did some of the groundwork in the Spring/Summer '15 releases but supporting this use case is still a ways out.

Comment: How can I redirect from one lighting page to another lightning page through a click on a component link? @shannonsans

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question - there are folks in this community who are better with Lightning than I am :)

Comment: @shannonsans Maybe there's a new update to this? At least there's the Actions API now which suggests it might be possible?

Comment: @shannonsans Is this now possible in '17?

Comment: Not sure - I haven't been at Salesforce since September 2015, and haven't had a chance to dig into this recently. Lightning made it possible to expose global quick actions in the header a couple of releases back, which may solve this, and also made it possible to turn a Lightning component into a quick action, which might also help.